# How to restore zoom for special part when whole page is zoomed in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML page:

```
<body>
  ....
  <div class="no-zoom">
    ....
  </div>
</body>
```

I set zoom option for `body` tag.

I want to set zoom to 1 in some part with `no-zoom` class.

So I made CSS as follows:

**CSS:**

```
body {
  zoom: 1.5;
}

.no-zoom {
  zoom: 1; // it's not working.
}
```

But it's not working. Please anyone help.

Comment: What do you see in devtools? Is the second CSS rule even being applied? Is it being overwritten by another rule?

Comment: Zoom is non-standard, I wouldn't use it. [MDN Docs on zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

Comment: @Deni J. I'm using webstorm. second rule was not overwritten by another rule.

Comment: @AmauryHanser Thanks for your advice, but now is there way to fix current state? i cannot change my code without zoom. because there is lot of code in real site actually.

Comment: You can't reset a zoom to 1 like that. If you want to scale down something that is 1.5 it's normal size it needs to scaled back 33.3% to bring it back to the original size. That said, zoom is not really appropriate for scaling a page. That's not what it is for.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for your help. could you post it answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom is a bit like `em` measurements, with a child zoom of `1` you are basically saying zoom the same as the parent.  As a further example, a child zoom of `1.25` would by a 25% zoom more than the parent zoom.

One option available to you is to zoom the direct children of the `body`, excluding `no-zoom`

```css
body > :not(.no-zoom) {
  zoom: 1.5;
  color:red; /*Just to highlite :not*/
}
```

```html
<div>Zoomed</div>
<div class="no-zoom">No Zoom For You!</div>
```

Comment: `body > :not(.no-zoom)` is not working. but `.no-zoom { zoom: 0.67; }` is working for me.

Comment: @Daniel.Wang, weird, it should: https://jsfiddle.net/hvqwogtd/